# apex error for trigger

Tags: error-messages

hi all  i have written this code but it is showing error  expecting this ';' instead of ')'  can anybodt tell me the answer?

```
trigger triggeroncountry on country__c (before insert) {

    Lead mylead = new lead();
    mylead = [select id from lead where country = 'india'];

    for(country__c c=trigger.new) {
        if(c.country_name__c== 'india') {
            mylead.phone= '+91'+ mylead.phone;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of colon you are using assignment operator inside for loop. Trailhead is best resource to learn the basics of apex.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code make no business sense, to be honest. You are updating single (or multiple) lead's phone number by running a loop on another object. i.e. Country__c. Both objects should be related in some way, and then use [*maps*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) to have that relation in your code.

Comment: Why do you need a trigger on `Country` to update leads from `India`, you are not getting any information from `Country` object rather you are hard-coding the `code` which can be done in `Lead's` trigger as well (`before insert`).

Answer (score 3):

First of all I am not sure what this code is supposed to go. Guess is its trying to insert a lead but below are my observations

```
trigger triggeroncountry on country__c (before insert) {
Lead mylead = new lead();
```

//Dont directly assign to a sobject variable use a list, if the record is not there the below code will result in NPE(null pointer exception)

```
   mylead = [select id from lead where country = 'india'];
```

in the below code trigger.new is a list you need to change the for loop variable like this and you should use after insert instead of before insert

```
 for(country__c c : trigger.new){

    if(c.country_name__c== 'india')
         {
             mylead.phone= '+91'+ mylead.phone;
         }
}
```